# Creating a Regular Expression pattern to match space delimited string

Tags: php, regex

I have file with a lot of rows (over 32k). Rows looks like:

```
34 Item
5423 11Item
44    Item
```

First digits it is IDs. I want make assoc. array: *array("34" => "Item", "5423" => "11Item", "44" => "Item")*

1. IDs can be from 1 to 5 length (1 - 65366)
2. Name of item can start from with a digit
3. Minimum one (BUT can be MORE than one) space between IDs and Items name

So main divide is space or certain number of them. Using PHP.

Comment: Looks like I forgot to add that the name can consist of several words. For example: 3411   Items Items100. So and end at digits

Comment: Does the name of item contain spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$data = <<<'LOD'
34 Item
5423 11Item
44    Item
546
65535 toto le héros
65536 belzebuth
glups  glips
LOD;

$result = array();

$line = strtok($data, "\r\n");

while($line!==false) {
    $tmp = preg_split('~\s+~', $line, 2, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    if (count($tmp)==2 && $tmp[0]==(string)(int)$tmp[0] && $tmp[0]<65536)
        $result[$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1];
    $line = strtok("\r\n");
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method which doesn't check validity of data but might works. It explodes every line according to space(s) and put results in a `$res` associative array.
For information, [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split) allows to split a string with a regex.

```
$res = array();
foreach($lines as $line) {
     $data = preg_split('/\s+/', $line);
     $res[$data[0]] = $data[1];     
}
```

If you really want to check your conditions you can add some `if` statement, with the ID limit:

```
$res = array();
foreach($lines as $line) {
     $data = preg_split('/\s+/', $line);
     $idx = intval($data[0]);
     if($idx > 0 && $idx < 65366) // skip lines where the ID seems invalid
         $res[$data[0]] = $data[1];     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_math) with named capturing groups:

```
preg_match('/^(?<id>\d+)\s+(?<name>[\w ]+)$/', $row, $matches);
```

`$matches['id']` will contain the ID and `$matches['name']` will contain the name.

```
while (/* get each row */) {
    preg_match('/^(?<id>\d+)\s+(?<name>[\w ]+)$/', $row, $matches);

    $id = $matches['id'];
    $name = $matches['name'];

    if ($id > 1 && $id < 65366) {
        $arr[$id] = $name;
    }
}

print_r($arr);
```

Example output:

```
Array
(
    [34] => Item
    [5423] => 11Item
    [44] => Item
    [3470] => BLABLA TEF2200
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/91573)

Comment: Why not `$cont = file_get_contents($file); preg_match_all('/^(?<id>\d+)\s+(?<name>\w+)$/m', $cont, $matches);`?

Comment: @SharanyaDutta: There are over 32K rows (as he said in the question), so it can be slow. And if he's already iterating through all the rows, `preg_match()` would be more suited.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is works good but not correctly in one situation: when string ends with a digits. For example:

3470 BLABLA TEF2200

In $matches['id'] I got: ... 3470 2200 ... But there should be only 3470

Comment: @MaximDroy: Ah. I updated the regular expression to handle spaces, too. I've also added an example and a demo to help you understand it better. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use https://www.php.net/preg_split

i.e.

```
 preg_split("/ +/", $line);
```

It will return an array of strings.